# How to obtain the Jacobian Matrix with respect to the inputs of a keras model neural network?

Tags: tensorflow2.x, automatic-differentiation

I recently started learning and using automatic differentiation to determine the gradients and jacobian matrix of a neural network with respect to a given input. The method suggested by tensorflow is the `tape.gradient` and `tape.jacobian` method. However, I am not able to obtain the jacobian matrix using this method due to some bug in tensorflow. It works when I calculated `tape.gradient(y_pred, x)`, but not the jacobian matrix, which should have a shape of `(200,3)`. I am open to other ways to calculate the jacobian matrix, but I am more inclined to use automatic differentiation methods within Tensorflow. The current version I am using is Tensorflow 2.1.0. Greatly appreciate any advice!

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# The neural network accepts 3 inputs and produces 200 outputs. The actual values of the inputs and outputs are not written in the code as it is too involved.
num_inputs = 3
num_outputs = 200
num_hidden_layers  = 5
num_neurons = 50
kernel = 'he_uniform'
activation  = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)

# Details of model (MLP)
current_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
current_model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_inputs,)))
for i in range(num_hidden_layers):
    current_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=num_neurons, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=kernel))
current_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=num_outputs, activation='linear', kernel_initializer=kernel))

# Finding the Jacobian matrix with respect to a given input of the neural network
# In this case, the inputs are [0.02, 0.4 and 0.12] (i.e. 3 inputs)
x = tf.Variable([[0.02, 0.4, 0.12]], dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = x
    for layer in current_model.layers:
        y_pred = layer(y_pred)

jacobian = tape.jacobian(y_pred, x)

print(jacobian)
```

Below is the error returned. I removed some parts for privacy purposes.

```sh
StagingError: in converted code:

C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\parallel_for\control_flow_ops.py:183 f  *
    return _pfor_impl(loop_fn, iters, parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\parallel_for\control_flow_ops.py:256 _pfor_impl
    outputs.append(converter.convert(loop_fn_output))
C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\parallel_for\pfor.py:1280 convert
    output = self._convert_helper(y)
C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\parallel_for\pfor.py:1453 _convert_helper
    if flags.FLAGS.op_conversion_fallback_to_while_loop:
C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\flags.py:84 __getattr__
    wrapped(_sys.argv)
C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\absl\flags\_flagvalues.py:633 __call__
    name, value, suggestions=suggestions)

UnrecognizedFlagError: Unknown command line flag 'f'
```